# How to find a limit given two values

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $x_1=0$, and $x_2=1$; $x_n=\frac{x_{n-1}+x_{n-2}}{2}$ I know that $\lim x_{n}=\frac{2}{3}$, but I don't know how to apply the fact that I have two values, I have tried doing $x_n=\frac{x_{n-1}}{2}+\frac{x_{n-2}}{2}$ and adding $3$ to both of them, then $\frac{x_1}{2}+\frac{x_2}{2}=\frac{0}{2}+\frac{1}{2}$ but it doesn't add up, how can I proceed with it?

Comment: Are you looking for $lim_{n\to\infty} x_n$?

Comment: Hint $x_{n}-x_{n-1}= -\frac{1}{2} (x_{n-1}-x_{n_2}) = \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2^{n-1}} (x_{2}-x_{1})$ and you find $x_n =(x_{2}-x_{1}) \sum_{i=1}^n  \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2^{n-1}}$

Comment: Yes, I am looking for $lim_{n\to \infty}x_n$

Comment: Thanks,  NN2 helpful

Comment: @PeterP123: I would start by writing $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4,\cdots$ in base $2.$